# overflow auto doesn't work on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a problem with `overflow-auto`. This property is working very well in laptop/desktop but it is not working on mobile devices.

https://bdevg.com/articles/Testing%20overflow%20in%20mobile%F0%9F%8F%83%E2%80%8D%E2%99%80%EF%B8%8F%205f9a2c91f4c1090008e5237f

Open the above page in mobile view or on any mobile device. You can notice this add a scrollbar at the bottom of `Overflow...Overflow...Overflow...Overflow...Over....` in laptop/desktop view. But, it doesn't add the same scrollbar at the bottom of `Overflow...Overflow...Overflow...Overflow...Over....` in mobile view, instead, it makes the whole page scrollable including header and footer.

```css
.tui-editor-contents pre {
    margin: 2px 0 8px;
    padding: 18px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #f5f7f8;
}
```

This code adds overflow scroll property. You can edit the in-browser dev console.

## Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your class="MuiContainer-maxWidthSm" a default value

```
.MuiContainer-root {
max-width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: If the user will view this page on mobile devices on width *400px* or less, then it will add a scroll bar. The relative width is not working.

Comment: try  rem,If you don't set a fixed width, the page will not appear in the style you need

Answer (score 0):

## TRY THIS

```
.tui-editor-contents pre {
    margin: 2px 0 8px;
    padding: 18px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #f5f7f8;
    hieght:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: `width:100%` doesn't work. But setting `width:300px` is working. The problem with this approach is, i need to set width on every viewport.